# publish DFS namespaces?

Tags: dfs, namespaces

We have multiple domain controllers and file servers, and have recently begun migrating to DFS.  Everything works quite well, but one thing has me scratching my head...  DFS namespaces not found on the AD/DNS server responding are not displayed when you browse \\domain.local\, though they work perfectly correct if you go directly to \\domain.local\namespace.

Is there a way to "publish" the namespaces, either all of them or selectively, so that they appear when browsing \\domain.local\ ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing to `\\domain.local` will connect to the shares of one of your DC's. If your domain controllers are not setup as DFS roots for the namespace, the share will not be created on the domain controller and, therefore, won't be displayed when connecting to the domain UNC path (which, again, just connects you to one of the domain controllers).

If you add your domain controllers as additional DFS root servers to your existing namespaces, it should work as you describe.

edit: Adding the DC's as DFS root servers to your existing namespaces will create the root shared share on your DC. Thus, when browsing to `\\domain.local` the namespace share will be displayed.

Comment: Allow me to clarify:  some of our file-servers are not AD/DNS servers.  They just have the file-server / dfs roles installed.  I would like those namespaces to show up when browsing \\domain.local\, and not just the namespaces on the domain servers.

Comment: I understand what you want. I was trying to explain why it didn't work and also explained what you needed to do to make it work as you want. Added more clarification to my answer.

Comment: Your suggestion might be plausible... but only if the DC's shares were not writable... it wouldn't do to have people sending files to the wrong server.  Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: Setting the DC as a root for that namespace doesn't actually mean they write data there. The targets within the namespace still connect to where you set them. This is how DFS works.